# CRFlexibleTimer - memory leaks using Instruments Version 7.3 (Crittercism)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, crittercism

I'm testing the memory leaks in my app using **Instruments Version 7.3**. 
In the timeline pane, a leak appears as a red bar. Clicked on the Leaks instrument in the timeline pane to display leak-related information in the detail pane and chosen Call Tree from the detail type list in the navigation bar of the detail pane. Under the Call Tree display settings, selected **Invert Call Tree** and **Hide System Libraries**.

A list of method calls related to any detected leaks is displayed like this screenshot.

[image: Memory leaks detail pane]

I didn't get what is **CRFlexibleTimer**. Can anyone help me out of this?

Double-clicked the method call in the stack trace to display its code in Instruments. But, It is showing only memory address and Xcode button at the top of the detail pane also like disabled.

Can anybody help me with this thing?

Comment: I am from Apteligent Support. Can you send us these details along with your registered email address and the affected app name/app ID on support@apteligent.com and we will be able to look into this for you in more detail.

Comment: Co-founder of Apteligent here, can you also send us the version of the SDK?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated into latest version 5.6.5 (Dec 9, 2016) - GA. Then also same memory leaks exists.

Comment: @crittercismrob I updated **Crittercism** iOS SDK into latest one **5.6.6**. Now there is no memory leaks from Crittercism. It's all green tick. Thanks for the new update and fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update into latest version of **Crittercism 5.6.6** SDK.

**NOTE:** if memory leaks happen from Crittercism SDK.